# How much damage do Scorchers deal upon death?

Tags: boom-beach

I was looking at the [Scorcher's Stats](http://boombeach.wikia.com/wiki/Scorcher) in addition of the latest update. The wiki states:

> - When destroyed, the Scorcher explodes which deals damage to nearby Buildings and Troops.

The amount of damage given to nearby troops and buildings and replaced with a "?". Why is the amount of "death damage" listed as unknown? How much damage does the Scorcher deal upon death? Does it differ between buildings and troops?

Comment: I think they weren't able to test it yet, while you can see the scorcher damage-stats in the menu ingame. Don't forget that this is the newest troop.

Comment: Shouldn't the makers preset the death damage?

Comment: Yes I think so, but you cannot see this number somewhere ingame. If you click on the armory, you can clearly see how much damage the scorcher can do, but there is no number that shows the damage of thei own explosion. The wiki isn't directly connected to Supercell. The entries there are found/made mostly by the community (though some of them have connetions to Supercell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the [Wiki](http://boombeach.wikia.com/wiki/Scorcher) was updated.

- Level 1 Death Damage - 3,500
- Level 2 Death Damage - 3,850
- Level 3 Death Damage - 4,240
- Level 4 Death Damage - 4,660
- Level 5 Death Damage - 5,120
- Level 6 Death Damage - 5,640
- Level 7 Death Damage - 6,200
- Level 8 Death Damage - 6,820

Those are the new stats for the Scorcher's Death Damage.